# Linq to XML : Problem with colon in the xml tags

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

Here's the code to retrieve the value in the content tag:

```
   var returnVerse = from item in xmlTreeVerse.Descendants("rss").Elements("channel").Elements("item")
                              select new VerseModel
                               {
                                   Verse = item.Element("content").Value,
                                   Url = ""
                               };
```

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
                    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
                    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
                    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

  <channel>
    <title>text</title>
    <link>text</link>
    <item>
      <title>text</title>
      <content:encoded>
        Text
      </content:encoded>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I can't query "content:encode" because it is invalid to query the ":" operator.  Please help.

Answer (score 4):

That "colon operator" is a namespace.  You need to query with a namespace as well.  You use namespaces like this:

```
XNamespace content = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
Verse = item.Element(content + "encoded").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, so mapped back to `content:encoded` for this question

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get(@"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");

var xelems = xmlDoc.Descendants().ToList();

nodes.ForEach(n => n.Element(XName.Get("encoded", ns.NamespaceName)).Value);

var elems = from x in xelems 
  select x.Element(XName.Get("encoded", ns.NamespaceName)).Value
```

If you want to quickly test this works on a public RSS feed, run this code in a console app or on [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) up here on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1611160).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
item.Element("content").Value
```

Try this:

```
item.Element(XName.Get("encoded", "content")).Value
```

If `item.Element()` returns null there, you may need to use this instead:

```
item.Element(XName.Get("encoded", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/")).Value
```

Comment: Yea, that didn't work.  The second parameter of XName.Get is for the namespace.

Comment: Ah, oops.. well, swap them around. :)  (I will edit my answer to do so.)